# SQL Database Backup failures

Tags: sql-server

The size of DB is 1.1TB and some times when it is backing up it is throwing the error.

> The operating system returned the error '1359(failed to retrieve text
>   for this error. Reason: 15105)' while attempting 'SetEndOfFile' on
>   '\Dive\sql\Stage_backup_2018_04_25_001501_1259003.bak'.  BACKUP
>   DATABASE is terminating abnormally.  10 percent processed.  20 percent
>   processed.  30 percent processed.  40 percent processed.  50 percent
>   processed.  60 percent processed.  70 percent processed.  80 percent
>   processed.  90 percent processed.  Processed 178873592 pages for
>   database 'CDL_IRT_Stage', file 'CDL_IRT_Stage' on file 1.  100 percent
>   processed.  Processed 52537 pages for database.

The job is getting error and got the failure message as above but a backup file is created in the folder. Iam not sure whether this is a complete backup or not.

--Space is not the issue because we had over 2TB of free space on this.
--Sql server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Can some one had any experience on this kind of error before.

Responses are appreciated.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: `\Dive\sql\Stage_backup` is definitely *not* a valid path. Are you trying to backup to a slow network share perhaps? What statement did you use? If you used the GUI click on the `Script this` button at the top left and post the generated script here

Comment: If you google the error message you'll see a lot of people have the same issue with slow network storage.

Comment: Backup is running from long days but error happens some times and gets sorted by it self

Comment: Precisely like an issue caused by a slow share. Post the command and *actual* error. You can't expect people to help when you don't even post the command you used